# AWS CDK Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret

Tags: aws-cdk, region, aws-secrets-manager

In our project, we store all secrets in us-east-1 region (in the secrets manager). Now, we are deploying a new CDK project to us-west-2 region, this project should use the secrets from us-east-1 by fully specified secret ARN.

Example:

```
import * as secretsManager from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager';

...

const mongoDbCredentials = secretsManager.Secret.fromSecretAttributes(this, id, {
  secretCompleteArn: props.config.mongoDb.credentials.arn,
});
```

**Problem**:

This error happens in attempt to deploy new project:

"Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 918e74b7-bef8-4b6c-b8c0-f9c901037806; Proxy: null)"

**Expected result:**

We expect the new project will be successfully deployed with secrets from another region.

Comment: You need to replicate secrets to other regions per doc, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/create-manage-multi-region-secrets.html